# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for Lebesgue-Stieltjes integrals?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, stieltjes-integral

I am wondering whether the following result is true:

Let $F: [0, m] \rightarrow [0, 1]$ be a non-decreasing right-continuous function and $q: [0, m] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ be measuable. Suppose that the integral $\int_0^m q dF$ exists. Then, whenever $F$ is differentiable at $c \in [0, m]$, we have
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dc} \int_0^c q(z) dF(z) = q(c) F'(c).
\end{equation}

Is there a reference which contains result? Thank you.

Comment: False even for integral w.r.t Lebsgue measure (i.e. $F(Z)\equiv z$ and $m=1$). You need some additinal hypothesis on $q$ (like continuity).